# maven ant task variable issue

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant

I have a maven antrun task specified in my pom file, and its job is to copy some files from one place to another on compile phase. However ant does not recognized eclipse.home variable ?.. i tried with other variables and i am just running blank? What variables does maven-antrun-plugin have??

my plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <copy
                        todir="${eclipse.home}/workspace/location/src/main/webapp/realtime">
                        <fileset
                            dir="${eclipse.home}/workspace/location/src/main/webapp/realtime" />
                    </copy>
                    <copy
                        todir="${eclipse.home}/workspace/location/src/main/webapp/reports">
                        <fileset
                            dir="${eclipse.home}/workspace/location/src/main/webapp/reports" />
                    </copy>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse can recognize this property while editing your file because it is set in the Properties tab when you go to Window -> Preferences -> Ant -> Runtime.

If you are running the Maven build from the command line or in Eclipse but using an alternate JRE in the JRE tab of the Run Configuration, Ant will not recognize the property. If you try to run the Maven build using the workspace JRE, however, it may recognize it because the property is defined in the Eclipse workspace configuration.

The best solution is to always define your property in your POM so that the antrun plugin always recognizes it even if you run the Maven build from command line. You can define properties in the pom.xml as follows:

```
<properties>
    <property.name>propertyValue</property.name>
</properties>
```

Comment: hmm, i see :). but i noticed that when i define a property ${ECLIPSE_HOME} this is not resolved by maven?. what is the Maven variable for eclipse home ??.

Comment: Where did you define the ECLIPSE_HOME?

Comment: eclipse_home is predefined, but when i include this as a property it does not recognize it

Comment: First eclipse.home or ECLIPSE_HOME most probably is where your Eclipse is installed and not where your project workspace is. Are you sure the workspace folder is in the installation folder of Eclipse? Second why don't you use ${basedir} which points to the path where your pom.xml exists.

Comment: actually my workspace is inside installation folder. Normally when i use ECLIPSE_HOME within other maven tasks its resolves just fine, but for this particullar one it just doesn't like it... ${basedir} does not apply to this scenario because i am copying files that are in different directory to the one that the pom is located